# Is Azure Virtual Machine storage lost after an instance is shut down?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

If I install something on my Azure Virtual Machine, lets say NotePad++ and some personal files, will that data be lost if the virtual machine is shut down/rebooted?

I know that on Amazon EC2 that data is lost after the instance is shutdown and trying to confirm if Azure has this same annoying "feature".

Comment: VMs in Azure tend to come pre-allocated with temp-storage drives, these you will lose on shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about Windows Azure's new (in preview) VM feature, which you probably are, the answer is that you *won't* lose your storage. VMs are backed by persistent storage.

By the way, the answer is the same on EC2 if you're using an EBS-backed VM.